# Import of 'random' and 'pylab' in one file doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python script where I need to import python standard `random` library and also import `pylab` functions. I wrote a simple program to use 'random' in a script which works file but as soon as I add the import of pylab, it stops functioning. See below.

Sample script using `random`:

```
import random
#from pylab import *

def getRandomAngle():
    return random.randint(0,360)

def getRandomAngleList(num):
    angle_list = []
    for i in range(num):
        angle_list.append(getRandomAngle())
    return angle_list

#Call randomAngle method to print a random angle
randomAngleList = getRandomAngleList(5)
print randomAngleList
```

Prints the expected output:

```
[96, 163, 212, 344, 77]
```

Now, `Uncomment` the import of pylab in `line 2` of above program and then it throws the following error -

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randint'
```

Could anyone please help me to understand, how to include both imports? I believe that there is some random function inside pylab which is causing the issue, but not sure. I am using Python 2.7 version.

Comment: And now you know why "star" imports are evil. They are useful in certain special situations, or when you're just playing around in the interpreter, but please don't use them in normal scripts.

Comment: Note: if you feel that writing `pylab` every time is too long: `import pylab as pl`. It makes it shorter and all pylab entities are still in their dedicated namespace.

Comment: @farsil It also works, if I use `from pylab import *` but import random using an alias - `import random as ran`. So that seems more convenient right?

Comment: @GauravSachdeva it works, but I would still be wary of using the wildcard import. One reason is future-proofing: what if hypothetically the pylab developers decide to add a `ran` function to the `pylab` module? Your code will break again, and you'll have to find another alias.

Comment: @farsil Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `pylab` has a function named `random` and this will overwrite the `random` module you imported.

A solution is to avoid `from pylab import *` and say instead

```
import random
import pylab
```

prefixing `pylab` functions when you need them.

In python using `from ... import *` can be problematic because this will possibly overwrite already defined functions/classes/variables in your code.